# pass an array of strings from C# to a C++ dll and back again

Tags: c#, c++, string, dll, char

I have looked around the googleverse and stack overflow and have seen several similar questions to this but none of the answers I have found have worked for me.  I am a new member so I am not allowed to comment on answers in someone else's question to ask for clarification so I have had to resort to asking my own.

Ok so I am trying to pass a string array from a C# application to a C++ dll and then grab that information in another C# application.  I believe I am passing to C++ properly but I can't get proper strings back from the dll.

I am passing to C++ like so:

```
[DllImport("KinectPlugins.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern void SetGrammarData(string[] strArr, int size);


    public void SetGrammar(string[] strArr)
    {
        SetGrammarData(strArr, strArr.Length);
    }
```

My C++ code looks like this:

```
#define EXPORT_API __declspec(dllexport)
#pragma data_seg(".SHARED")
    char** grammarData;
    int grammarDataLength = 0;
#pragma data_seg()
#pragma comment(linker, "/section:.SHARED,RWS")

EXPORT_API void SetGrammarData(char** strArr, int size)
{
    grammarData = strArr;
    grammarDataLength = size;
}

EXPORT_API int GetGrammarDataLength()
{
    return grammarDataLength;
}
EXPORT_API char** GetGrammarData()
{
    return grammarData;
}
```

My code for then grabbing the information in my other C# application looks like this:

```
[DllImport("KinectPlugins.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetGrammarData();
[DllImport("KinectPlugins.dll")]
private static extern int GetGrammarDataLength();

public string[] GetGrammar()
{
    int size = GetGrammarDataLength();
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    IntPtr ptr = GetGrammarData();
    IntPtr strPtr;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i = " + i);
        strPtr = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ptr);
        list.Add(Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(strPtr));
        ptr += Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
    }
    return list.ToArray();
}
```

In theory this should work based on my research as I have seen several other people use almost the same code.  In practice, what happens is I pass in:

```
SetGrammar(new string[] { "b", "a" });
```

and what comes back out the other side is:

```
stringArray[0] = 
stringArray[1] = H-▬l☺
```

In case some can't view it for some reason or another stringArray[1] is equal to H, -, a thick line, l and a happy face symbol.  This is obviously not what I put in.

Does anyone have an idea where I could be going wrong with this?  I have been banging my head against this problem for quite a while and could really use some help as it feels like I am missing something really simple here.

**Edit:**
as per antijon's suggestion I did change my SetGrammarData to make a copy of the strings but I am still running into an issue.

new code:

```
(inside the data_seg)
wchar_t* grammarData;
(end data_seg)

EXPORT_API void SetGrammarData(wchar_t* strArr, int size)
{
    delete[] grammarData;
    grammarData = new wchar_t[size];
    std::memcpy(grammarData, strArr, sizeof(wchar_t) * size);
    grammarDataLength = size;
}
EXPORT_API wchar_t* GetGrammarData()
{
    return grammarData;
}
```

Now I end up with this output:

```
stringArray[0] = 8
stringArray[1] =
```

The C# code has remained the same.  Is there something else I need to change that I am missing?

**Edit2:**
Just realized that wchar_t is like a char, not a string, not sure why I thought it behaved like a string.  Back to the drawing board, need to figure out how to best copy a wchar_t**.  Not that experienced with C++ but I don't think it's possible to get the length of a wchar_t* without passing it in myself but I will have to look into it.

**Edit3:**
Finally got it working properly.

Here is what I ended up with:

```
(inside the data_seg)
std::wstring* grammarData;
(end data_seg)

EXPORT_API void SetGrammarData(wchar_t** strArr, int size)
{
    delete[] grammarData;
    grammarDataLength = size;
    grammarData = new std::wstring[size];
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        grammarData[i] = std::wstring(strArr[i]);
    }
}

EXPORT_API const wchar_t** GetGrammarData()
{
    const wchar_t** wct = new const wchar_t*[grammarDataLength];
    for(int i = 0;i<grammarDataLength;i++)
    {
        const wchar_t* t = grammarData[i].c_str();
        wct[i] = t;
    }
    return wct;
}
```

**Edit4:**
Thought I had it working properly, was incorrect.  I was testing with an exe passing back to itself but when passing through the dll to another exe nothing would come through.  I now have it working:

```
(inside the data_seg)
wchar_t grammarData[32][50] = {};
(end data_seg)

EXPORT_API void SetGrammarData(wchar_t** strArr, int size)
{
    grammarDataLength = size;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        wcscpy(grammarData[i], strArr[i]);
    }
    grammarDataChanged = 1;
}

EXPORT_API wchar_t** GetGrammarData()
{
    wchar_t** wct = new wchar_t*[grammarDataLength];
    for(int i = 0;i<grammarDataLength;i++)
    {
        wct[i] = grammarData[i];
    }

    grammarDataChanged = 0;
    return wct;
}
```

Comment: did you try passing the array as a `ref` parameter?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372061/c-sharp-struct-no-parameterless-constructor-see-what-i-need-to-accomplish and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345945/attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an-indication-that-o and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344929/pointers-in-c-sharp-to-retrieve-reference-from-dllimport-function

Comment: and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343272/dllimport-unmanaged-non-net-dll-to-net-project-representing-char-and-void

Comment: Tejas: Do you mean pass a char** by ref into GetGrammarData in the second C# application instead of returning a char** in order to retrieve the information?

0A0D: I will take a look at those links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of possible problems here:

1. By default, .NET will marshal as `wchar_t`, not `char`.  You will need to mark your input/output string parameters with [MarshalAsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx) to use char.
2. If you want to keep the strings, you will need to make copies of them within the C function.  The pointers given to you in the function call to `SetGrammarData` are not guaranteed to persist.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't even considered #2.  I guess it goes to show I have been working on this problem for too long and had too many iterations to have forgotten something like that.  I will try fixing that as you are likely correct with that being my major problem.  I may not have it tested today though as I have to leave very shortly.  May need to wait for tomorrow to accept this answer.

Comment: hmm, I tried:

    EXPORT_API void SetGrammarData(wchar_t* strArr, int size)
    {
        delete[] grammarData;
        grammarData = new wchar_t[size];
        std::memcpy(grammarData, strArr, sizeof(wchar_t) * size);
        grammarDataLength = size;
    }

    EXPORT_API wchar_t* GetGrammarData()
    {
        return grammarData;
    }

but now all I get back is:

    stringArray[0] = 8
    stringArray[1] =

Is there something else I am doing wrong that you are aware of?